# asp.NET MVC ローカライズの多言語切り替えボタンをつけたい

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, postgresql, asp.net

環境 ASP.NETMVC 　C# HTML CSS jquery3.3.1 postgres4

https://qiita.com/yuu-eguci/items/40f171dff0f8c2cb4748
以上の記事を参考に多言語切り替えのボタンを装着してみたところ
javascriptのajaxが反応しなくなり、DBのデータが取れなくなりました。

htmlの記述はローカライズできました。
ブラウザの言語切り替えによるローカライズは成功しました。

言語切り替えボタンによるDBのローカライズがうまくいきません。
わかる方いましたら、よろしくおねがいいたします。

Comment: $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../../contoroller/Action',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:

Answer (score 0):

> javascriptのajaxが反応しなくなり

ajax で利用している URL を ページ相対にするのではなく `/` で始める
サイト先頭からの URL に変更してみてください。

ブラウザで F12 キーを押して AJAX 通信の 応答内容を確認してみてください。

Comment: $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../../us/Contoroller/Action',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:
                {  上記のurlだと英語のみデータは引っ張ってこれます。　　us の部分をjaに切り替えたいのですが、どのように記述すればいかわかりません。　　ブラウザの言語切り替えverだと、usの部分は未記述で切り替えられます。ボタンでの切り替え方法を教えてください。@ksystem

Comment: リンク先の 記事を見ましたが、現在の ページが ja なのか en なのか culture という名前の Cookie に保持しているようなので、その情報を元に ajax で利用する URL で us なのか ja なのか判断してはいかがでしょうか？